# How to get user creation details

Tags: solaris, date, useradd, shadow

Kindly assist to to get user creation details (date and time) and users login details in Solaris 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try by dates of `~/.login` file or via first login date in `wtmp`. But none of these methods with give trustworthy answer to your question.